# Pandas select rows if ID appear several time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table like this:

```
CustID  Purchase  Time
A       Item1     01/01/2011
B       Item2     01/01/2011   
C       Item1     01/02/2011   
A       Item2     03/01/2011
```

I would like to select rows with CustID appear more than 1 in the table.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could work:

```
counts = df['CustID'].value_counts()
df[df['CustID'].isin(counts.index[counts > 1])]
```

Result:

```
  CustID Purchase        Time
0      A    Item1  01/01/2011
3      A    Item2  03/01/2011
```

Comment: This was my approach, plus one.  To make it more efficient, you can pass `sort=False` to `value_counts`

Comment: Nice answer! Your brace/parenth on the second line are backwards, though. I'd edit myself but want to avoid the risk of destroying your formatting on my phone :)

Answer (score 15):

```
df[df['CustID'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

This finds the rows in the data frame where there exist duplicates in the `CustID` column.  The `keep=False` tells the `duplicated` function to mark all duplicate rows as `True` (as opposed to just the first or last ones):

```
  CustID Purchase        Time
0      A    Item1  01/01/2011
3      A    Item2  03/01/2011
```

**EDIT**

Looking at the docs for `duplicated` it looks like you can also do:

```
df[df.duplicated('CustID', keep=False)]
```

Though this seems to be about 100 µs slower than the original (458 µs vs. 545 µs based on the example dataframe)

Comment: I think the fastest solution.

Comment: I think this is the most intuitive approach since we deal with duplicates. +1

Comment: Thank you! I have never thought that I could use 'duplicated' in this case

Answer (score 11):

Use [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration)

```
df.groupby('CustID').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

```
  CustID Purchase        Time
0      A    Item1  01/01/2011
3      A    Item2  03/01/2011
```